# Android WebView 2way SSL (custom client certificate handling)

Tags: android, ssl, webview, client-certificates

I would like to support 2way SSL in an Android `WebView`:

```
@Override   public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView
    view, WebResourceRequest request) {

    HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection =
    (HttpsURLConnection)urlConnection;

    httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new PortalHostnameVerifider());

    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = this.getSSLContext().getSocketFactory();
    httpsConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    httpsConnection.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());

    String contentType = urlConnection.getContentType();

    }
```

The `SocketFactory` looks like this:

```
public SSLContext getSSLContext() {

        String kmfAlgorithm = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(kmfAlgorithm);
        kmf.init(this.trustStore, this.truststorePassword.toCharArray());

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(this.trustStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");      
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
}
```

The `TrustManager` section is working fine but the client cert section is not working.

I expect that

```
onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
```

is called when the server requests the client cert during the SSLHandshake but that is never triggered. Is my understanding (expectation) correct?

```
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

The above line tells the SSLContect to use the default `KeyManager`. Does this have an impact on the `onReceivedClientCertRequest`?

I need to handle the clientcert request on the fly so I can't provide a keystore initialized `KeyManager`.

How can I make 2waySSL working in the `WebView`?
How can I make `onReceivedClientCertRequest` being triggered?

Thanks

Comment: I initialize the sslContext now like this:

sslContext.init(new KeyManager[]{myKeyManager}, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null); 

This triggers now the getPrivateKey function in my custom X509KeyManager. That seems to be right approach but how would I achieve this in the WebView itself. I guess by using the httpsURLConnection inside the webview I take control an the WebView mechanism do not kick in.
But how to do it with the WebView mechanisms?